# Yii2 Image not display after remove frontend/web

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've apply pretty URL and remove frontend/web from URL but images are not working.

help to access the images on frontend

I've refer this [url](https://gist.github.com/erycamel/bb0e5653977d620e68ce) to create pretty URL

**Code: myapp/.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp/(assets|css|images)  
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Code: /myapp/frontend/config/main.php**

```
use \yii\web\Request;

$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);


return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',

    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'class' => 'common\components\Request',
            'web'=> '/frontend/web'
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],


        'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => [

                         '<alias:login|logout|signup>' => 'site/<alias>',   
                          'users'=>'user/index',                                             
                      ],
                ],
        ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Apply pretty URL simply like this:

1. Delete the .htaccess file you have created inside `myapp` and create another one inside `myapp/backend/web` and `myapp/frontend/web` folders like below:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule . index.php

2. Add the urlManager component in your `common/config/main.php` like below:

   [image]

   3. Remove the urlManager component you have created inside `myapp/frontend/config/main.php`
   4. Now i think you will get your images easily like below:

`@web`is the base URL of your currently running Web application (frontend/web). It has the same value as `yii\web\Request::$baseUrl`.

So you should get your images like below:

```
<?php echo Html::img('@web/images/test.png', []); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo Html::img( Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/images/test.png', []); ?>
```

Assuming you have a folder "images" in your web directory containing your images (test.png in the example)

Comment: I've tried this but getting 404 error image not found

Comment: That means the problem comes from somewhere else. Update your question and add your code, so that we can see the way you apply pretty URL and remove frontend/web from URL.

Comment: for both (backend & frontend) URL rewrite rule write in the common/config/main.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`<img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/img/image1.jpg">`

Comment: I've tried this but getting 404 error image not found

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly path it will show right now